# Atlas linguistique de la France

Tags: vocabulaire, prononciation

J'étudie la methode de glottochronogie et l'Atlas linguistique de la France est presque le plus idéal pour ça, mais ya quelques questions.
Dans l'image il y a le liste Swadesh et lá, j'ai marqué les mots qu'il n'y a pas dans l'Atlas de rouge. Pouvez vous évaluer si les mots en rouge ont la diversité (comme bouche//gol).

Le mot os. Il y a quelque chose comme roujet dans quelques points dans la carte du mot os. Est-ce de l'origine différente?

Nager//Nadar. Il y a des places avec le son dz où g ou d se lève habituelment, alor je ne voi pas l'origine, pouvez vous ce commenter? De quel son pourrai-t-il évoluer lá, dz? (marqué de bleu)

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Using an off-site image hosting service makes it harder for us to see your images. Please upload them here so that they can be inlined and we can avoid having them expired, removed, or replaced with images most people would rather avoid seeing.

Comment: "Nager" vient de navigare > navgare, les formes du nord-est avec un /v/ ou un /w/ de navigare > naviare et le type "nadar" de natare. Les formes un /z/ ou un /dz/ à la transition des domaines d'Oil et d'Oc sont du type "nager". /(d)z/ est le résultat normal de la palatalisation de /ga/, voir les cartes 712 "Jardin" et 239 "Charger" pour des résultats similaires (par example /'dzardjĩ/ et /tsar'dza/ au point d'enquête 705)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Je me limite à la première question du post original, qui concerne des mots de la liste de Swadesh qui ne seraient pas dans l'ALF. Il n'est franchement pas clair si la question concerne leur variété phonologique ou lexicale.

- THAT : Comme en français, la distinction entre ISTE et ILLE s'est effondrée dans la plupart des langues d'Oïl et les remplacements du type -ci et -là pas toujours bien contrasté. Pour le pronom démonstratif, les types ça (ECCE HOC ILLAC) et aco (ECCUM HOC) dominent dans les domaines d'oïl et d'oc, respectivement, mais la question se complexifie beaucoup si on se penche sur les déterminants ou les pronoms sujets.
- SMALL : En plus des cognats du français petit, il y a au moins le type PITTINUM bien répandu dans le domaine d'oc, comme pichon, pitchoune, etc
- WOMAN : COMMATREM et FEMINAM devraient être tous les deux utilisés, peut être aussi (MEAM) DOMINAM. Au niveau phonologique, la voyelle du "com-" initial est souvent passé à schwa.
- MAN (ADULT MALE HUMAN) : présent dans l'ALF : cartes 119 "un bel homme" et 1457 "de beaux hommes"
- PERSON (INDIVIDUAL HUMAN) : présent dans l'ALF, mais seulement pour le domaine d'oc et dans un contexte syntactique particulier : 1513 "combien de personnes". Dans le domaine d'oïl, je sais d'expérience que GENTEM peut être utilisé à la place de PERSONAM dans ce contexte et y compris au singulier (y a ène djin stampeye padvant vo-n-uxhe : il y a une personne débout devant ta porte)
- GREASE (ANIMAL FAT) : l'ALF a 463 "engraisser" (fatten up) qui ne montre pas beaucoup de diversité (quelques localités dans le nord-est qui préservent le /k/ de CRASSIAM, ce que je peux confirmer être toujours d'actualité et des formes de type /amãde/ dans le centre, qui semblent venir d'EMENDARE et ne pas avoir de lien avec la graisse)
- COLD (OF WEATHER) : présent dans l'ALF : 612 "froid" présente une note disant qu'il s'agit du substantif (le froid) qui désigne soit la sensation tactile de froid ou le temps froid.

Comment: Merci! Je dis de lexical. Et la carte '...homme', je ne suis pas sûr si il sagit de 'male' lá? Et sur 'personne', le liste Swadesh est assez particulier, alor il peut être seulment au singulier, n'est-ce pas. Même avec le froid

Comment: Et pouvez-vous, s'il vous plait, me dire si cette carte 'femme, ma femme' dit de woman ou wife? Je ne vois pas!

Comment: Mais je vois qu'on manque beaucoup! Presque tout les mots en rouge ont la diversité.

Comment: @SeRəgəzinski Femme, ma femme = wife, unambiguously. The french prompt for both maps with "homme(s)" is "attractive adult man/men", also unambiguously. "Gens" is normally a pluralia tantum that means "people" but in some varieties there's a singular usage meaning "person".

Answer (score 0):

[image][image][image][image]

Body must be at least 30 characters; you entered 0.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).